# Cannot recognize image upload at Google Drive in js

Tags: javascript, http, file-upload, encoding, google-drive-api

i'm trying to upload image file at google drive, using oauth token & fetch url.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads
Perform a multipart upload, HTTP.
when i try to upload, fetch url response returns status 200, and in google drive, file is in there. But can't see(recognized no support img).

it's my header

```
method: post 
Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
Content-Type: `multipart/related; boundary=${boundaryString}`
Content-Length: ${body.Length}
```

and it's my body

```
--`${boundaryString}`
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"name":"myimage.png","description":"Upload image","mimeType":"image/png"}

--`${boundaryString}`
Content-Type: image/png; Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

data:image/png;base64,iVBO......TkSuQmCC
--`${boundaryString}`--
```

response :

```
status: 200 url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart"
body: {
  id: "~~~~"
  kind: "drive#file"
  mimeType: "image/png"
  name: "myimage.png"
```

when i go to drive, it exist. it's details correct(name, description, mimeType),
but can't recognize like another images.(file format is not supported.)
when i check  `<img src ="data:image/png;base64,iVBO......TkSuQmC" />` it works.
could tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Please remove `Content-Type: image/png;` from the data part.
- Please remove the header of base64 data.

When above points are reflected to your request body, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified request body:

```
--`${boundaryString}`
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"name":"myimage.png","description":"Upload image","mimeType":"image/png"}

--`${boundaryString}`
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

iVBO......TkSuQmCC
--`${boundaryString}`--
```

#### Note:

- In this case, the line breaks are important. Please be careful this.
- In this modification, it supposes that your access token can be used for uploading the file to Google Drive.
- Although I'm not sure about your actual script, if you use Javascript, how about the following modified script?

  ```
      var data = `--${boundaryString}
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

    {"name":"myimage.png","description":"Upload image","mimeType":"image/png"}

    --${boundaryString}
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

    iVBO......TkSuQmCC
    --${boundaryString}--`;
  ```